# How to quickly check if row exists in PySpark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, exists

I have a PySpark dataframe like this:

```
+------+------+
|     A|     B|
+------+------+
|     1|     2|
|     1|     3|
|     2|     3|
|     2|     5|
+------+------+
```

I want to do a lookup on the table to see if a specific row exists. For example, for the test of `A = 2`, `B = 5` the code should return `True` and for `A = 2`,`B = 10` the code should return `False`.

I tried this:

```
df[(df['A'] == 1) & (df['B'] == 2)].rdd.isEmpty()
```

Unfortunately, this code takes a long time to execute, and since this is a lookup that will be performed many times (for different values of A and B), I would like to have a quicker method of accomplishing this task.

Other solutions that I am considering are:

- Converting the PySpark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe because the row lookups are faster
- Using `.where()` or `.filter()` though from what I have tried, I do not anticipate either being substantially faster
- Using `.count()` over `isEmpty()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to create a spark dataframe from the entries that you want to look up, and then do a `semi join` or an `anti join` to get the rows that exist or do not exist in the lookup dataframe. This should be more efficient than checking the entries one by one.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([[2,5],[2,10]],['A','B'])

result1 = df.join(lookup, ['A','B'], 'semi').withColumn('exists', F.lit(True))

result2 = df.join(lookup, ['A','B'], 'anti').withColumn('exists', F.lit(False))

result = result1.unionAll(result2)

result.show()
+---+---+------+
|  A|  B|exists|
+---+---+------+
|  2|  5|  true|
|  2| 10| false|
+---+---+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark function [`ANY`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#any) offers a very quick way to check if a record exists inside a dataframe.

```
check = df.selectExpr('ANY((A = 2) AND (B = 5)) as chk')

check.show()
#  +----+
#  | chk|
#  +----+
#  |true|
#  +----+

check = df.selectExpr('ANY((A = 2) AND (B = 10)) as chk')
check.show()
#  +-----+
#  |  chk|
#  +-----+
#  |false|
#  +-----+
```